# R Markdown CV (modern cv) errors - tinytex?

Tags: r, latex, markdown, tinytex

I am trying to make a CV using markdown, and the default modern CV template. Whenever I try to knit I get the following error.

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \whatsappsocialsymbol
> undefined.
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile cv-attempy.tex. See
> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
> cv-attempy.log for more info.

Things I have tried:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
tinytex::tlmgr_update()

tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()

options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

And lots of other things involving uninstalling and reinstalling tinytex.

I really don't know how to fix this and make it knit. Any suggestions? Anybody able to get moderncv to run?

I am able to use the awesomecv template which works fine...but I would like moderncv to work!

Comment: Update on this: I have got it to work...one of the above things I tried must have worked after all

Comment: why did you tag this question with opencv and computer vision?

Comment: don't blindly tag things. you tagged `computer-vision` and `opencv` (a library for computer vision), neither of which have to do with **curricula vitae**. simply typing `cv` can result in this site rewriting that to other tags. -- check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/